# Mapping Function in dictionary with parameters

Tags: python

I need call the function which matches the string in a dictionary with a parameter.

```
def createResources(argument, jsonObject):
    switcher = {
        "subnet": checkSubnet(jsonObject),
        "virtualNetwork": checkVnet(jsonObject),
    }


def call_to_function(jsonObject):
    for key in jsonObject:
        print("The current key is {}".format(key))
        createResources(key, jsonObject)
```

Expected Output:
 The Create resource should call only call the function from key when it is matched in switcher dictionary.

Comment: I think the issue is clear from the code. Lets not close this one.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. By the way, you appear to be mixing/combining multiple naming conventions. Keep it simple, use the `lower_case_with_underscores` style for variable and function names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `switcher` dictionary should only reference the function you want to call. Save the call itself for when you use it. I moved the dictionary out of the function so that it isn't rebuilt on each call, and put stubs in for the called functions just to keep things tidy.

```
def checkSubnet(jsonObject):
    print('checkSubnet', jsonObject)

def checkVnet(jsonObject):
    print('checkVnet', jsonObject)

_createResources_switcher = {
        "subnet": checkSubnet,
        "virtualNetwork": checkVnet,
}

def createResources(argument, jsonObject):
    return _createResources_switcher[argument](jsonObject)


def call_to_function(jsonObject):
    for key in jsonObject:
        print("The current key is {}".format(key))
        createResources(key, jsonObject)
```

That code passes the entire jsonObject to the called functions and raises a key error if the key isn't mapped in switcher. We could make some changes

```
def checkSubnet(value):
    print('checkSubnet', value)

def checkVnet(value):
    print('checkVnet', value)

_createResources_switcher = {
        "subnet": checkSubnet,
        "virtualNetwork": checkVnet,
}

def createResources(argument, value):
    if argument in _createResources_switcher:
        return _createResources_switcher[argument](value)
    else:
        # any error logic here...
        pass


def call_to_function(jsonObject):
    for key, value in jsonObject.items():
        print("The current key is {}".format(key))
        createResources(key, value)
```

Comment: OP mentions "from key when it is matched in switcher dictionary", suggesting there could be cases without match: I'm afraid this code could throw a KeyError. Better use `get()`, no?

Comment: @Arnaud -  Or the caller could wrap this in an exception handler. The problem with `get` is what do you do if you get a None... raise a `KeyError`? Only use `get` if there is some error policy other than raising an exception. Then `get` becomes quite reasonable.

Comment: I suggested `switcher.get(argument, lambda x: None)(jsonObject)` so as to avoid `None` being returned, but instead have a "useless" function. But you have a point, this should better be more explicit.

Comment: @Arnaud - yes, providing a default is another way to handle it. You could even have a function that logs the error and continues. OP has lots of choices!

Comment: yes its generating Key Error, is there any way I can avoid the Error?

Comment: That would mean that `jsonObject` has keys other than "subnet" and "virtualNetwork". Is that an error and if so, do you want your program to stop? `KeyError` does that. You could catch that exception somewhere in the outer part of your program and let your user know. On the other hand, if you just want to skip keys that arent' in switcher, you could test for that.

Comment: BTW, I am passing the entire `jsonObject` to the function, should that be just the value for the key?

Comment: Hi @tdelaney
Thanks for help, I am able to get expected output